# Por quê, apenas parte dos dados, aparecem no php?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou fazendo um select, em uma tabela do meu banco de dados, para pegar todas as mensagens de todos os usuários. Porém, apenas as mensagens de 1 só usuário aparecem, as outras não!

php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X-Requested-With');

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$idUsuario = $data->idUsuario;
$idCep = $data->idCep;

//Busca nome do usuário
$pegaUsuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHEREidUsuario=:idUsuario");
$pegaUsuario->bindValue("idUsuario", $idUsuario);
$pegaUsuario->execute();

while ($linhaUsuario=$pegaUsuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $nome   = utf8_encode($linhaUsuario['nome']);
}

//Busca dados do cep
$pegaCidade=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cep WHERE idCep=:idCep");
$pegaCidade->bindValue("idCep", $idCep);
$pegaCidade->execute();

while ($linhaCidade=$pegaCidade->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $estado = utf8_encode($linhaCidade['uf']);
}

//Busca mensagens com estado, cidade, bairro e logradouro do usuário
$pegaMsgsEstado=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM avisosUF WHERE estado=:estado");
$pegaMsgsEstado->bindValue("estado", $estado);
$pegaMsgsEstado->execute();

$mensagens = array();

while ($linhaMsg=$pegaMsgsEstado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $idAviso = $linhaMsg['idAvisoUf'];
    $idUsuario = $linhaMsg['idUsuario'];
    $msg = $linhaMsg['msg'];
    $foto = utf8_encode($linhaMsg['foto']);
    $hora = $linhaMsg['hora'];

    $horaP = explode(':', $hora);
    $hora = $horaP[0].':'.$horaP[1];

    //Busca nome do usuário que envio a mensagem
    $pegaUsuarioRemetente=$pdo->prepare("SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario=:idUsuario");
    $pegaUsuarioRemetente->bindValue("idUsuario", $idUsuario);
    $pegaUsuarioRemetente->execute();

    while ($linhaUsuarioRemetente=$pegaUsuarioRemetente->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $nomeRemetente  = utf8_encode($linhaUsuarioRemetente['nome']);


    $return = array(
            'idUsuario' => $idUsuario,
            'nome' => $nomeRemetente,
            'msg' => $msg,
            'foto' => $foto,
            'hora' => $hora
        );

    $mensagens[] = $return;

    }
}

print_r($mensagens);
//echo json_encode($mensagens);

?>
```

Segue foto da tabela no banco:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar gravar todos os dados em uma variável com o `$pegaUsuarioRemetente->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`.

Ai só você executar um `foreach()` nesta variável, este método é mais simples e confiável.

Lembre-se, com o FETCH_OBJ vc irá criar objetos e não arrays. Exemplo: 
Além de ser `$variavel['nome'];`
utilize `$variavel->nome`.
Bem mais pratico.

Comment: Valeu @Romario Pires, mas já descobri quel era o problema.

Valeu mesmo pela tua atenção.